# Is it possible to use nested page-router-outlets in Nativescript 4.1?

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to use page-router-outlets without any undesired side effects in Nativescript version 4.1? Does navigation work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by ***nested***. The proper answer is that `page-router-outlet` is not intended to be nested (see details [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/969#issuecomment-327891442)). However, if you want to nest a navigatable content inside a static one, then this scenario is already supported.

I would suggest going through [this test application](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/ng-sample/app/examples/router) to see some of the supported scenarios for the `page-router-outlet` and also follow [this GithHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1351) where a feature request for nested routing is logged.

Other examples of flexible navigation can be found in [this test application](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/e2e/modal-navigation-ng/app).

Comment: I want to share sidedrawer code in all pages except login page. I thought that maybe I can use a page-router-outlet at the top to navigate from login page to other app pages and another page-router-outlet for navigating pages inside sidedrawer body. I can use router-outlet but in this case probably back navigation won't work as expected.

Comment: Share the sidedrawer along all your pages (using `root` sidedrawer) and then just disable it on the login page as done here https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L44-L45

Comment: In the linked app above the root sidedrawer is placed in app.component https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/app.component.html